# Google Sheets LOOKUP Function returning the wrong values?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I'm creating a crypto tracking spreadsheet and I'm getting some strange results using the LOOKUP function.
I have two named ranges:

[image: Named Ranges]

The symbol range is called USDCoinSymbols
and the coin name range is called USDCoinNames

Here are some function results when I try using the LOOKUP function:

[image: Results]

Apologies for the mixed casing on the search term. I was experimenting, but
it seems the LOOKUP function isn't case sensitive (for example, BNB returned the correct coin name).

I also tried the inverse, looking up a coin symbol with a coin name (2nd result) and that works fine.
I spent a good couple hours trying to figure this out.

Am I missing something or is this a bug?

Edit: Here is a [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KDi-uhDyK077NvFarmfEGayz0MyD094_oJKFAeaBsyg/edit?usp=sharing) to sample spreadsheet and I'm using the CoinGecko API to get this data.

I'm trying to pull the coin name using the symbol to fill up a table I'm creating.

Comment: It is unclear -at least to me- what you are trying to do. Please read how to and [share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/117311) so as you can be easier helped.

Comment: @marikamitsos I added a link to a sample spreadsheet. I'm trying to fill up the bottom table with information from the top table using a coin's symbol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a bug. It's just how `LOOKUP` works.

`LOOKUP` requires that all search-column information be in strict least-to-greatest order,  so it wouldn't work with your data.

I've added a new sheet ("Erik Help") which is a duplicate of your first sheet. In my sheet, I deleted your `LOOKUP` formulas from `B20:B27` and replaced them with one array formula. This formula uses `VLOOKUP` with FALSE as the final parameter, meaning that your data is NOT ordered in strict least-to-greatest order and that exact matches should be searched anywhere instead. This one formula fills all results for `B20:B`:

`=ArrayFormula(IF(A20:A="",,IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A20:A,B2:C14,2,FALSE))))`

If you are going to be applying this to a larger list elsewhere and want to use your named ranges, just replace `B2:C14` with `{USDCoinSymbols, USDCoinNames}`.

References:

- [LOOKUP](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3256570?hl=en)
- [VLOOKUP](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318?hl=en&ref_topic=3105472)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use the [VLOOKUP](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318) function instead

```
=INDEX(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A20:A25, {USDCoinSymbols, USDCoinNames},2,0)))
```

This single formula is all you need.
Since your lists are NOT sorted you should use `0` in the function

*(please -as always- adjust formula according to your ranges and locale)*

[image]

Comment: The formula works fine. Check your sheet noted as *"by marikamitsos"*